# local.properties Issue opening Android Studio project in another Computer with IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, project

I have a Android Studio Project that I need to send to a colleague that uses IntelliJ, the local.properties are defined for my SDK location, and IntelliJ can't find it... There is a way of sending this project without having to open it in Android Studio before? If so, how?
[The error description in Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsbIr.png)

Comment: Why does he not change the `local.properties` to his sdk location?

Comment: Because as said by her, the project I sent is for a cross platforms project, and it should work with whatever program they use to run it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `local.properties` are meant for the local working environment and has basically nothing to do with collaborating. Conveniently, `Android Studio` detects that the SDK path is wrongly and offers to change it.

That is basically the same as copy-pasting the actual path to the SDK location on your system to the local.properties.

Comment: So how could I do it to not require the local.properties, like a library?

Comment: Why is changing a path to local SDK such a problem?

Comment: @DavidHazan Do not overcomplicate things. This is a basic task as searching the SDK folder on the system and copy pasting the path to the properties.....